# Symfony load too slow

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I'm building a  Symfony application and when I work on it, it is too slow. I have wondering what can cause this so I went in the profiler timeline to see what is going on but I was amazed that all those classes have very big data 10 MB, 22 MB and so on. See the picture:

[image]

This is my Object bundle. The yellow is my own class with my twigs. I do not understand what is this delay and what is this big data.... Can someone explain to me what is going on and how can be optimized this because on a production if it is like now  it is too slow... Total time 3962 ms

Here is the controller - nothing fancy generate from the console with minor changes:

```
<?php

namespace George\ObjectsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use George\ObjectsBundle\Entity\Object;
use George\ObjectsBundle\Form\ObjectType;

/**
 * Object controller.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/object")
 */
 class ObjectController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Object entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="object")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session =  $request->getSession();

    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->findAll();
   // echo $locale;
    /*
    $category = new Object();
    $category->translate('bg')->setTitle('Chaussures');
    $category->translate('en')->setTitle('Shoes');
    $category->translate('bg')->setDescription('Chaussures');
    $category->translate('en')->setDescription('Shoes');
    $category->translate('bg')->setAddress('Chaussures');
    $category->translate('en')->setAddress('Shoes');
    $category->setMode('a');
    $category->setLat('12');
    $category->setLongt('12');
    echo $category->translate('bg')->getTitle();
    $category->mergeNewTranslations(); $em->persist($category);
    $em->flush();
    */
    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="object_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("ObjectsBundle:Object:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Object();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('object'));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Object entity.
 *
 * @param Object $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Object $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObjectType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('object_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="object_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Object();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="object_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Object entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="object_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Object entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Object entity.
*
* @param Object $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Object $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObjectType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('object_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="object_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ObjectsBundle:Object:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Object entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('object_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Deletes a Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="object_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Object entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('object'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Object entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('object_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
        ->getForm();
}
}
```

The main twig for the admin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

{% block title -%}<title>Admin</title>{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 {% block menu -%} {% endblock %}
 {% block body -%} {% endblock %}
{% block javascripts -%}
{% javascripts
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/fine-uploader.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/datatables.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js'

%}
<script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
{% block readyjs -%}

{{ tinymce_init() }}
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function post_order ( ord, url)
    {
        $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { elem: ord }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    //  alert( msg );
                });
    }

$(document).ready(function () {

    var optionsDatatables = {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
        ]
    }
    if($('#dattab').hasClass('allow-order'))
    {
        //if we want more properties
        // optionsDatatables.rowReorder = {
        //selector: 'tr',
        //   update: true,
        //   dataSrc: '.ord-id'
        //  }
        optionsDatatables.rowReorder = true;
    }

    var table =    $('#dattab').DataTable(optionsDatatables);
    var order;
    if($('#dattab').hasClass('allow-order')) {
        $('#dattab').on('draw.dt', function () {
                var rows = table.rows().data();
                var ord = new Array();
                for (var i = 0, ien = rows.length; i < ien; i++) {
                    ord[i] = rows[i].DT_RowId;
                }
                order = ord;
                $('#save_sort').fadeIn();
        });
    }
    $('#save_sort').click(function(){
        console.log(order);
       post_order(order,$('#dattab').data('url'));
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });


});
   </script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The index which extends the base

```
{% extends "CoreBundle::admin_inner.html.twig" %}
{% block body -%}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {#{{ app.request.locale }}#}
            <h1>Object list</h1>
            {% for locale in ['en', 'bg'] %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')| merge({'_locale' : locale})) }}">
                       {{ locale  }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ app.session.get('_locale') }}{#
{{  app.request.locale }}#}
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table  table-hover table-bordered" id="dattab">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Mode</th>
                        <th>Lat</th>
                        <th>Longt</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Updated</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for entity in entities %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
                            <td>{{ entity.translate(app.session.get('_locale')).title }} </td>
                            <td>{{ entity.translate(app.session.get('_locale')).description }} </td>
                            <td>{{ entity.mode }}</td>
                            <td>{{ entity.lat }}</td>
                            <td>{{ entity.longt }}</td>
                            <td>{{ entity.translate(app.session.get('_locale')).address }}</td>
                            <td>{% if entity.created %}{{ entity.created|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
                            <td>{% if entity.updated %}{{ entity.updated|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ path('object_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"
                                   class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"
                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit</a>
                                <a href="{{ path('admin_floor', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"
                                   class="btn btn-info"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"
                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></span> Floors</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('object_new') }}">
                        Create a new entry
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the inner with the menu:

```
{% extends "CoreBundle::admin_base.html.twig" %}
{% block menu %}
    {{ include('CoreBundle::menu.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello George, mind showing your templates?
Keep in mind, that in dev-environment some things will slow down your application: Minor Caching, Profiling, Debugging, Logging etc.
This does not necessarely mean, your prod environment will be slow as well.

Comment: Ok but it is too slow i cannot imagine that this need 4 seconds... I have include the code :)

Comment: The first request after a cache:clear will always be slower than the following ones. Was that the case?

Comment: No this is not the case. How can I switch to production mode?

Comment: For production mode you just need to use the regular URL without accessing through the /app_dev.php

Answer (score 0):

I would first check whether all your frontend resources are loading correctly (scripts, images, css). 
This can considerably slow down you app.
You can check it in firebug or developer console.

Comment: I'm showing that i have 4 seconds delay only in the php before to load any script in the timeline of the profiler console of symfony.

Comment: Look on frontend - like js scripts, look in db queries, how many results are you fetching from db? for many queries (it's shown in the bar) and do you have php well configured? (php 7, opcache enabled?)

Comment: I have optimized many sites but not based on symfony the truth is that this is the admin and there is many javascript dependency. But i see that the scripts are loaded  for 50 ms each tomorrow  will make more investigation.

Comment: you are right about the opcache i forget about it.... This will be the first thing in the morning!